# Audio playing too fast on lubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I did a total reset of my netbook (Asus eee pc 1201ha) and I installed Lubuntu 13.10.
The matter is that, whatever player I use, my music files are always played too fast. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo sed -i 's/load-module module-udev-detect/load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0 tsched=0/g' /etc/pulse/default.pa; pulseaudio -k`

Comment: PulseAudio is a major PIA; I'm not sure why Ubuntu doesn't ship with these options as default since it fixes almost all the audio issues most people report.